# How do I set an accessibility label in SwiftUI while still being able to test the visible text in a UI test?

Tags: ios, swiftui, xctest

Suppose I have an element on screen that shows the time left until an event which looks like this:

> Time left: 3mo 20d 19h 59min. 21s.

But when using VoiceOver it will read it as

> three mo, twenty d, nineteen h, fifty nine minutes, twenty one's.

So I put an accessibility label so it reads like

> three months, twenty days, nineteen hours, fifty nine minutes, twenty
> one seconds.

**However now in my UI test I can only see the accessibility label.** I've lost the ability to test the text that's actually visible on the screen. I want to test both the visible *and* audible text, not just one or the other.

Am I doing it the wrong way and if so what is the correct way, or is there another way to test the visible text after adding an accessibilityLabel?

Thanks :)

Comment: UI testing is based on accessibility replacing label you cannot access overwritten value, `cause it is invisible for accessibility engine anymore. A possible approach is to move those hidden values at model (view model) layer (instead of hardcoding in-view, for example) and test that layer separately. Also you can take screenshots and verify them.

Comment: I already have viewModel and other unit tests but you've made me think. Why do I need to test that value in both places? The idea is for "end to end" tests but maybe it's overkill. I haven't done screenshot testing but it seems even more overkill (if used for this purpose alone). Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems from this perspective we are ONLY testing accessibility and navigation in UI tests. Whether it has custom text or not, it's the accessible value we are testing. I'm not sure if I like this or not but it's interesting if this is a design choice. On Android I can test both things.

Comment: Another thing is that I'm also testing the accessibility value in unit tests too. Which makes me wonder what's the point of testing accessibility in UI tests either? What is the purpose of UI tests in iOS? If I'm testing accessibility it's feeling incomplete if I don't also have these screenshot tests. I think the developer should be able to decide how they want to test their app. These seems like a strange design choice. Anyway as least I got an answer :)